# Filtering entities by subtype with NHibernate.Linq

Tags: c#, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

Given this inheritance mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
    <class name="User" table="[User]" abstract="true">
        <joined-subclass name="SubUser1" table="SubUser1">
            <key column="UserId" />
            ...
        </joined-subclass>
        <joined-subclass name="SubUser2" table="SubUser2">
            <key column="UserId" />
            ...
        </joined-subclass>
        <joined-subclass name="SubUser3" table="SubUser3">
            <key column="UserId" />
            ...
        </joined-subclass>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

how do I query for all instances of `SubUser2` and `SubUser3`? I realize I can do this:

```
session.Linq<User>().OfType<SubUser2>()
```

but that only allows me to filter by a single type. I tried this:

```
session.Linq<User>().Where(user => user is SubUser2)
```

but that resulted in this error:

```
could not resolve property:  of: User
```

Any ideas on how to express a query against multiple sub-types?

Comment: I have the same problem. Do you know how to do this in criteria? When it's possible in criteria, it must be possible to make the "is" operator working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this is not possible. Perhaps it will be in the future. I know they accept patches :-)

I only have about 500 records and 4 types, and am usually querying on 2 or 3 types at the same time. For now, I am applying the filter on each type in the database, then concatenating the result sets and doing ordering and paging in-memory.

It is not the most efficient solution, but works just fine. I chose not to add a superfluous discriminator column to the User table solely to enable this query.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
// Get them in 2 queries
var sub2 = session.Linq<SubUser2>().Select(x => x).ToList();
var sub3 = session.Linq<SubUser3>().Select(x => x).ToList();

// Join together in memory
var sub2And3 = sub2.OfType<User>().Union( sub3.OfType<User>() );
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't let me express queries on the database. I would be applying filtering, ordering and paging in-memory.

Comment: Maybe then you could apply Union on the database (though not sure if it is supported).

Comment: I tried it out when I read your answer, Union is not supported.